# ERB tag within link_to_function JavaScript call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to dynamically set which id a JavaScript call uses, as I have multiples rendered on each page, I'm trying to use

```
<p id="add_rider_link_section_<%= section.id %>"><%= link_to_function("Add a Rider",
"Element.remove('add_rider_link_section_' + <%= section.id %> + '' ); Element.show('add_rider')") %></p>
```

It's failing on

```
"Element.remove('add_rider_link_section_' + <%= section.id %> + '' );
```

Can you not embed erb tags within JavaScript like that?  If not, how else do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already in a ruby method. So you don't need to embed ERB.
You just have to use ruby.

```
<p id="add_rider_link_section_<%= section.id %>">
    <%= link_to_function("Add a Rider",
            "Element.remove('add_rider_link_section_" + section.id + "'); Element.show('add_rider')") %>
</p>
```